# All Old Order Emails are going to all customers when setting cron.php on server Magento

Tags: email, magento, cron

When i set cron.php on server with SSH, all customers are getting old order emails.
How can i get which emails are in queue so that i can tell my client that these emails are now in queue.
Can someone help me on this.

Thank you

Comment: what version of Magento are you using?  Any email comms plugins (such as SMTP pro) installed?

Comment: we are using Magento 1.9.2.2. i have checked and found that , Mailchimp module installed in store.

Answer (score 0):

Check the core_queue_table and the core_email_queue_recipients tables on your server. Those tables may contain emails already sent so you have to run the core_email_queue_clean_up cron first.